# Unable to successfully redirectAction in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2

I am running struts 2 and have already successfully connected to my SQL server, everything is working fine except I am trying to redirect my users and admins differently, as in when someone logs into the web, I want to redirect him to either the homepage.jsp (if he is a regular user) or control.jsp (if he is an admin of the page) and I am not getting this part to work, I have the following codes but both the users and admin both get redirected to the admin page. Would be nice if anyone could tell me my mistakes, or any other info I missed out to add.

struts.xml

```
<!-- Login Function -->
<action name="Login" class="Actions.Login">
        <result type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">LevelofAccess</param>
        </result>
        <result name="input">Index.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="LevelofAccess" class="Actions.LevelofAccess">
        <result name="success">/WEB-INF/Control.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/WEB-INF/Homepage.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

Login.java(don't think error is here)

```
package Actions;
import Objects.ConnectSQL;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;

public class Login extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {
private Map session;

private String username = "";  
private String password = "";  


ConnectSQL connectSQL = new ConnectSQL();

public Login() {
}

@Override
public void validate(){
    // Check if username exists on session map.  If it exists, it means that user log in before
    Object usernameobject = session.get("username");  
    if (usernameobject == null) {
        //nothing will happen
    }
    else {
        // Username exists on session map, i.e. user has  already logged in.
        return;
    }

    // Connect to MS SQL Server database.
    String message = connectSQL.connect("localhost", 1433, "Online", "Eugene", "Eugene"); //Shopping = Databasename, Eugene = user, Eugene = pass
    if (message != null) { //if message null, means connection OK
        addActionError(message);
        return;
    }

    // Check if username and password are correct.
    boolean userfound = false; //Set to false as if it is found, will be set to true later
    ResultSet select = connectSQL.executeSQLStatement("SELECT * FROM Users"); //Choosing the value inside the table
    try { // looping to find the username
        while (select.next()) { 
            String selectusername = select.getString("Username"); //Field name in table <<
            String selectpassword = select.getString("Password");

            if (username.equals(selectusername)) {
                userfound = true;
                if (!password.equals(selectpassword)) {
                    addFieldError("password", "Incorrect password");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        addActionError(e.getMessage());
        return;
    }

    if (userfound) {
        // At this point, username and password are correct.
        // So we add the username to the session map to enable subsequent actions to be able
        // to check that user has already logged in.
        session.put("username", username);  
    }
    else
        addFieldError("username", "Invalid username");
}

@Override
public String execute() {
return SUCCESS;
}

@Override
public void setSession(Map session) {
    this.session = session;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
}
```

LevelofAccess.java (1 is my sql data for "user" and 2 is my sql data for "admin")

```
ConnectSQL connectSQL = new ConnectSQL();

    String username;
public LevelofAccess(){
}


@Override
public void validate(){
Object usernameObject = session.get("username");
    if (usernameObject == null) {
        addActionError("Error: User is not found.  Please log in again.");
        return;
    }
    else
        username = (String) usernameObject;

    // Connect to MS SQL Server database.
    String message = connectSQL.connect("localhost", 1433, "Online", "Eugene", "Eugene");
    if (message != null) {
        addActionError(message);
    }

    ResultSet rs = connectSQL.executeSQLStatement("SELECT Type FROM Online.dbo.Users where Username = " + "'" + username + "'");
try{    
while(rs.first()){
    int gettype = rs.getInt("Type");
    if (gettype == 1){
    return;
    }
    else {
    // do nothing     
    }
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
}
}

@Override
public String execute() {
    return SUCCESS;
}

@Override
public void setSession(Map session) {
    this.session = session;
}
}
```

Comment: You need to return different results from the action method to use different configured results.

Comment: return different results? in what way, doesn't just having the "return" mean that it is return input by default??? if not what exactly are you implying? adding an additional action package??

Comment: Your action method `execute` always return `SUCCESS`. The `validate` method is for validation and it isn't action method (https://struts.apache.org/docs/action-configuration.html#ActionConfiguration-ActionMethods).

Comment: oh so basically i have to configure my results under the `execute` function?

Comment: In action method that you've defined in struts.xml for that action (`execute` is the default action method). Consider reading some tutorials first - https://struts.apache.org/docs/tutorials.html.

Comment: @EugeneLee `input` is a reserved result code used to prevent the action execution, `return` doesn't do that.

Comment: @RomanC ohh i understand that part now, i always thought 'return' automatically sends an 'input' to the action, so if i edit the codes under my `execute` method to something like `return "admin"`, and rename the result type of my struts.xml file, will be sufficient?

Comment: @EugeneLee It won't be sufficient, you have also to remove `validate()` method.

Comment: @RomanC i already tried that, currently my execute() method has both `return user` and `return admin` and i've already changed my struts.xml files respectively, but the users are still getting directed to the admin page, anything else that could be a factor?

Comment: @EugeneLee the first one is never performed, you need to change the logic to allow `return user`